# Re-purpose DD660 (DataDomain) for VM Storage

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, network-share, storage-area-network, network-attached-storage

We have an un-used DD660 (DataDomain) and an un-used x3650 M2 that we are wanting to use as a test bed for playing with Hyper-V as we look into it vs. VMware.

Has anyone used a DD660 is simply storage as opposed to a backup appliance?

Ideally, I would like it to be a SAN endpoint, but not sure if this is possible.

I'm primarily a network guy, but have begun to play with the storage/VM side of things so please feel free to ask for clarification and/or correct my terminology if I've made an error.

Comment: Performance is going to be not good, at best, as you're going to have 7200rpm drives + the inline data deduplication all conspiring against you.

Answer (score 1):

As a DataDomain is basically a "standard server", you can probably just install Linux/Windows on it, and use it as iSCSI target

Comment: While this may be an option, it also seems like one that will require A LOT of work to ensure driver availability...etc.  I do appreciate the pointer here though.

Comment: Well, I would not know how else you could use it. Hyper-V needs SMB2 as far as I know, and I'm not sure the DD supports that. Also it does not support iSCSI afaik, and Hyper-V is not so good with NFS :) So your options are pretty limited, I think.

Comment: Hyper-V needs SMB 3.0 and not 2.0 (if you mean storing VMs on a share). Yes, NFS is out of luck (politically).

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. SMB 3.0, my mistake. Even worse, as the DD almost guaranteed does not support that :)